# had proposed or proposed?

Tags: past-tense, past-perfect, past-vs-past-perfect

In the following paragraph, is it better to use 'had proposed the extended warranty' or 'proposed the extended warranty'?

> If the customer doesn’t want to pay and maliciously blows us off to try and get free service, you may reply to him/her in this way: We’ve asked our salesmen and they said that although the customer **had** proposed the extended warranty, he/she didn’t agree ultimately. Nevertheless, we also tried to ask our supervisor to make an exception for you, but our supervisor didn’t approve, considering that this exception may affect other customers’ rights.

Comment: You should avoid the "he/she" and "him/her" thing, use either the singular they or make your sentence plural.

Answer (score 1):

I think the past perfect tense works better here.

The simple past tense can make that portion look like a contradiction, that is, that the customer didn't ultimately agree with their own proposal.

- * although the customer proposed the extended warranty, he/she didn’t agree ultimately

Using the past perfect (as is the case with your quote) treats the customer's proposal as a *completed act*, one that they could disagree with later:

- although the customer had proposed the extended warranty, he/she didn’t agree ultimately

Answer (score 0):

I'll be honest: the whole "propose" thing isn't the only issue in that paragraph. I'd rewrite it like so:

> If the customer doesn't want to pay and is clearly attempting to receive free service, you may reply to him/her this way:
>
> I asked our sales department about your purchase, and although they originally proposed the extended warranty to you, our records show that you declined to purchase that warranty. Nevertheless, I also asked my supervisor to make an exception for you, but the supervisor did not approve. The justification given was that "this exception may affect other customers' rights in the future."

The wording in your original paragraph is very confusing, but it seems that this paragraph is meant to be given to employees as a script to follow in the event that a customer is causing problems.